# Why did my jello not set?

Tags: gelatin

To a 3 oz. box of orange jello I added 1 cup of boiling liquid (mandarin orange), then a pint of orange sherbet and finally the drained oranges.  The jello had a bubbled effect on top and did not set well.  Vanilla ice cream worked just fine; do I need to change something in order to use sherbet?

Comment: What is in the orange sherbet? Is the only flavor orange or does it have other fruits? Many "orange" fruits have an enzyme that prevents jello from setting, including pineapple, papaya, guava, and mango, and the box generally bears a warning about avoiding these (and other) fruits.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of fruits denature gelatin so it doesnt set.

All of the citruses, papaya (that has an enzyme called "papain" that breaks proteins), pineapple ("bromelin") and a lot of others cannot be used with gelatin without being very thoroughly cooked, as in boiled for one hour or so.

If you just brought mandarin oranges to a boil for using, that could be it. Or it could be the sherbet.